# Выгрузка данных с пробелами php

Tags: php, bootstrap, laravel

Выгружаю данные из базы,используя laravel, вот таким образом:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{ $product->avatar }}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{ $product->title }} </h3>
                    <p>{{ str_limit($product->description, 250, '...') }}</p>
                    <p><a href="{{ url('/lot', $product->id) }}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Подробнее »</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Данные выгружаются как надо, по 3 объекта на строку, но как только я удаляю несколько из них (из базы), на их месте появляются пробелы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему такое может происходить? Как это исправить? Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Тут проблема скорее в верстке, блоки выравниваются по float:left и на 2й строке 4й блок цепляется в 2 верхних.

Comment: Код верстки копировал из примеры Бутстрапа. Вы не подскажите как это поправить?

Comment: "3 объекта на строку" это выглядит так, а по факту у все в одной строке `.row`. Откуда копировали код? ссылку?

Comment: Вот отсюда http://bootstrap-3.ru/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: Третий блок больше по высоте, чем первые два. Выравнивайте высоту и все встанет на свои места.

Comment: Сейчас убрал вывод изображений - все нормально работает, похоже в них дело. А не подскажите, как сделать чтобы размер фото в каждой ячейке был одинаковым? Вне зависимости от реального размера изображения

Comment: Бахни бэкграндом и блоку один размер задай а там background-size: cover или contain чего больше понравится

Answer (score 1):

После вывода 3-его объекта, нужно вставить

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Бутстраповска сетка 4+4+4, потом "скидываем" clearfix и потом идет следующая строка

Comment: а если объектов 1000? в таком случае считать каждый третий объект?

Comment: заведите переменную в которой будет храниться текущая итерация цикла и если при делении на 3 будет целое значение, вставлять выше приведенную строку